# Magento2 - How to reduce Logout to homepage redirect time from 5 seconds to 2 seconds?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3

After Logout it is taking 5 seconds to redirect to `Homepage`.

I want to reduce those time to 2 seconds.

How can I achieve this one ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Copy this file :

> \vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\web\js\logout-redirect.js

to

> \app\design\frontend\Vendor\Theme\Magento_Customer\web\js\ogout-redirect.js

change

```
$($.mage.redirect(data.url, 'assign', 5000));
```

to:

```
$($.mage.redirect(data.url, 'assign', 2000));
```

Run this command : `php bin/magento c:f`

I hope this will help you.

If answer is true than accept it and mark it. **So it will help to other people.**

Comment: Any idea about, for which purpose it's used the 5 second redirect time? why they can not redirect on homepage without this timeout.

Comment: @Camit1dk, 5 seconds is default value set by magento. If you want to decrease time, you can use milliseconds like 500.

Answer (score 1):

override `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/logout-redirect.js`
to `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Customer/web/js/logout-redirect.js` and add below code

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (data) {
        $($.mage.redirect(data.url, 'assign', 2000));
    };
});
```

After override hit below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento ca:cl
php bin/magento ca:fl
```

please do not change directly in the core module because when you upgrade Magento then these changes automatically removed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in **logout-redirect.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (data) {
        $($.mage.redirect(data.url, 'assign', 2000));
    };
});
```

and change the message from logout.phtml